# Moving Laravel outside of docroot gives me problems with php's chdir() and path('sys')

Tags: php, path, laravel, laravel-3

I've been using Laravel 3 on a live website for a while, and decided to move the app to outside of docroot, delete the public_html folder, and symlink the public folder to the public_html one. I followed [solution 1 here](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=10022#p10022).

Having done that, my site has stopped loading, giving a 500 error. When I checked the error log in public/error_log, this message appears:

```
[05-Feb-2013 08:07:25] PHP Warning:  chdir() [<a href='function.chdir'>function.chdir</a>]: No such file or directory (errno 2) in /home4/indieweb/indiewebseries/paths.php on line 62
[05-Feb-2013 08:07:25] PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home4/indieweb/indiewebseries/public/laravel/laravel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home4/indieweb/indiewebseries/public/index.php on line 34
```

Just for reference:

```
// paths.php on line 62:
chdir(__DIR__);

// index.php line 34:
require path('sys').'laravel.php';
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I tried @TheShiftExchange suggestion, moved everything outside of docroot, and renamed public to public_html. I now get these php errors:

```
[07-Feb-2013 05:38:25] PHP Warning:  chdir() [<a href='function.chdir'>function.chdir</a>]: No such file or directory (errno 2) in /home4/indieweb/paths.php on line 62
[07-Feb-2013 05:38:25] PHP Fatal error:  require() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required '/home4/indieweb/public_html/laravel/laravel.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home4/indieweb/public_html/index.php on line 34
```

Comment: I can confirm that you dont need to symlink anything. Just rename 'public' folder to 'public_hmtl' - I do it on all my sites - and you dont need to touch anything inside laravel code - it just works.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Thanks! That's an excellent solution which I shall keep in mind for future sites, but due to a rather complicated setup of subdomains and directories, the app folder is actually inside another folder, so I (think I) need to symlink it.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange This is odd. I tried your suggestion, just to see, and it doesn't seem to be working either.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange When I try your suggestion, I get the php errors I added to the end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out all my problems were irrelevant. For some reason, the PHP settings in my hosting account were reset, and all I had to do was switch the PHP version back to 5.4 to fix everything.

Comment: Hi, can I know did you change any thing in php.ini? Mind let me know your folder structure, from Root till laravel folder?